# how to select date from KalViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using Kal Calendar control (link: https://github.com/klazuka/Kal)

I want to select date from calendar on screen, for example I have three dates: NSDate1, NSDate2, NSDate3. how should I select these dates from the calendar view of Kal

I am doing as follows:

```
KalViewController *kal = [[[KalViewController alloc] initWithSelectedDate:[NSDate date]] autorelease];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:kal animated:YES];
```

I have set the dataSource to calendar, but it didn't work

[image]